# How to hide the y-axis below 0, but still be able to plot values below zero? (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to hide the y-axis below 0, but still be able to plot values below zero? (matplotlib)

Currently I have this:
[image]

But what I want is this:
[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2], [-1, 1])

ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_xticks([])

# Move the left and bottom spines to x = 0 and y = 0, respectively.
ax.spines["left"].set_position(("data", 0))
ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
# Hide the top and right spines.
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

ax.set_xlim([0, 2])
# ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
```

I do not really know where to begin to fix this beside searching online.
I made an attempt at simply covering it by something else that is white, but dod not manage. And, I do not really like that approach as it does not seem very robust in terms of other features one might want to add later.
Other than that, I have simply tried to look in the documentation for matplotlib.axes and saw if I could find something useful.

Comment: Posted the code below with the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Look you wanted so?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2], [-1, 1])
ax.plot([2, 2], [0, 1], c="black", linewidth=2)
ax.plot([0, 0], [0, 1], c="black", linewidth=1)
lc = NullLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator())#Hiding the axis
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator())

plt.xlim([0, 2])
plt.ylim([-1.01, 1])

ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]